# mbedtls_printf not showing text on terminal

Tags: arm, mbed, dtls, mbedtls

I want to test DTLS libraries on two K64F board with ARM Mbed OS. I have just created a new project:

```
mbed new .
```

I have created a folder called source and copied there dtls_client.c obtained from the mbeddtls project page. I have changed the value of the SERVER_ADDR constant.

I have repeated this process with dtls_server.c file.

Both project compiled without errors.

```
mbed compile -m K64F -t GCC_ARM -c
```

I copied each bin file to a different board but when I connect to them through the putty terminal I cannot see anything. I have been using this connection with the rest of my programs and it works. I think It may have something related to connection (now it is 115200).

I see that the code uses a mbedtls_printf function to print messages. I have tried inserting some printf traces but I don't see them either. How should I set the terminal to be able to see something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@jordi,
Baudrate of 115200 should be OK for K64F.
You should verify that you have `DEBUG_LEVEL` set to a value higher than 0, and that Mbed TLS is compiled in debug mode.
Please compile your application with the following command:

`mbed compile -m K64F -t GCC_ARM -c --profile=mbed-os/tools/profiles/debug.json`

In addition, you should verify that your configuration file has `MBEDTLS_DEBUG_C` configured